# Elm Language What do the Multiple Types in a row (without the arrow) in a signature mean?

Tags: elm

In the Elm language, I'm having a hard time explaining my question...
In these snippets in elm:
I understand the signature in something like

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
```

where the parameters / output is separated by arrows, but how do I read / grok things like:

```
Sub Msg
Program Never Model Msg
```

In:

```
main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    program
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none
```

Comment: Looks like they are just the types to pass into the constructor - is that right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a type signature, parameter types are separated by `->`, with the last type being the return value.

If there are *no* `->` symbols, then it means it is a value of that type. In your `main` example, the type of `main` is `Program Never Model Msg`. It has no arrows, so it takes no parameters.

Now, each parameter and the return value in the type annotation may have several things separated by spaces, as in your `main` example. The leftmost is the type, followed by type parameters separated by spaces.

```
Program Never Model Msg
   |      |     |    |
   |      ------|-----
 type    type parameters
```

A type parameter is similar to Generics in a language like C#. The equivalent syntax in C# would be:

```
void Program<Never, Model, Msg>()
```

C# doesn't directly correlate because it has a different way of constraining generic type parameters, but the general idea holds.

The Elm guide doesn't currently have a great deal of info, but here is the [section talking about types](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/reading_types.html).

Comment: Thanks. Just so I'm clear, in my Model -> Sub Msg example, that function takes a Model as an input parameter, and returns a Sub of type Msg?

Comment: You could say that. Or `Model -> Sub Msg`  takes a `Model`, and returns a type `Sub Msg`. Where `Msg` is like a sub-type (or type parameter, as @ChadGilbert put it). The function outputs a subscription (`Sub`) which is handled by the elm runtime. The elm runtime will then pass on a message of type `Msg` to your update function. `Html Msg` in view functions is similar. `Html` is rendered to the DOM. Any messages from user interaction like clicking would be of type `Msg`.

Answer (score 6):

`Sub Msg`, `List Int`, `Program Never Model Msg`

`Sub`, `List` and `Program` are type constructors. You can think about them as functions that take a type and return another type.

By themselves, `Sub`, `List` and `Program` are not complete type. They are like a puzzle missing a piece. When one adds the missing piece, the puzzle is complete.

I usually read them in my head using the word `of` as in a `List` of `Int`s, a `Program` of `Never`, `Model` and `Msg`.